# How do I obtain the svn of the otg from bim360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

It seems that I am loading the urn for the .svf file from Bim360 instead of the otg. How do I get the urn of the otg file? The file have been converted using the https://otg-bim.herokuapp.com/ app.

Is there a service similar to Services.Forge.ModelDerivative.getManifest which I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is the same svn. Fault was that options requires autorization, even though I am allready autorized thorugh bim360 login. Providing the access token there and it works.